# Cross Validation on Train, Validation & Test Set

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

In the scenario of having three sets

- A `train` set of e.g. 80% (for model training)
- A `validation` set of e.g. 10% (for model training)
- A `test` set of e.g. 10% (for final model testing)

let's say I perform k-fold [cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) (CV) on the example dataset of `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`. Let's also say

- `10` is the `test` set in this example
- the remaining `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` will be used for training and validation

leave-one-out CV would than look something like this

```py
# Fold 1
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] # train
[1]                      # validation
# Fold 2
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] # train
[2]                      # validation
# Fold 3
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] # train
[3]                      # validation
# Fold 4
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] # train
[4]                      # validation
# Fold 5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9] # train
[5]                      # validation
# Fold 6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9] # train
[6]                      # validation
# Fold 7
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9] # train
[7]                      # validation
# Fold 8
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9] # train
[8]                      # validation
# Fold 9
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] # train
[9]                      # validation
```

Great, now the model has been built and validation using each data point of the combined `train` and `validation` set once.

Next, I would test my model on the `test` set (`10`) and get some performance.

What I was wondering now is **why we not also perform CV using the `test` set** and average the result to see the impact of different test sets? Meaning why we don't do the above process 10 times such that we have each data point also in the `test` set?

It would be obviously computationally extremely expensive but I was thinking about that cause it seemed difficult to choose an appropriate `test` set. For example, it could be that my model from above would have performed much differently when I would have chosen `1` as the test set and trained and validated on the remaining points.

I wondered about this **in scenarios where I have groups in my data**. For example

- `[1,2,3,4]` comes from group `A`,
- `[5,6,7,8]` comes from group `B` and
- `[9,10]` comes from group `C`.

In this case when choosing `10` as the test set, it could perform much differently than choosing `1` right, or am I missing something here?

Comment: This isn't a programming question and would be better suited to another stack exchange site. And I strongly suggest you read this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.12808

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your train-validation-test splits should be **randomly sampled** and **sufficiently big**. Hence if your data comes from different groups you should have roughly the same distribution of groups across train, validation and test pools. If your test performance varies based on the sampling seed you're definitely doing something wrong.

As to why not use test set for cross-validation, this would result in overfitting. Usually you would run your cross-validation many times with different hyperparameters and use cv score to select best models. If you don't have a separate test set to evaluate your model at the end of model selection you would never know if you overfitted to the training pool during model selection iterations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I think I get the point. So when having different groups, and each group having a different number of samples, stratified cv would be most fitting. Using that, I would then ascertain that my test set is "legit" and has similar distribution to the train and validation set, right?

Comment: Yes, more or less. But even better if you can get your dataset from a single source instead of combining multiple groups with different properties.